# Current page using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

I have a "Remove All" button that removes all records from a Ng-table and MongoDB.
In my system, there are several views and each and every one of them display different data. Now, I don't know how to get the current page name and send it as a parameter for remove. It is working only if I insert to the code the name of the view and click on the button.

HTML:

```
                <ul class="pager" ng-show="currentPage==login">
                   <li>
                    <button ng-click="removeLogs('$scope.logType')" id="deleteAllErrors" name="deleteError" class="btn btn-danger">Remove All</button></li>
                </ul>
```

Angular:

```
//  login, signUp, addErr, refreshLog, refreshErr, badProd - $scope.currentPage

    $scope.removeLogs = function(logType){
        console.log("Admin request to delete logType: "+logType+" & "+currentPage.current.name);
        var rmLogs = {
            'email': localStorageService.get('email'),
            'password': localStorageService.get('password'),
            'logType': logType
        };
        $http.post(''+appPath+'/removeLogs', rmLogs)
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.statusMsg = "Logs Deleted Successfully";
                console.log("Admin X has delete logType");
                $scope.updateAdmin();
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject ***$route*** in controller's DI and access the params like this.

```
var currentMethod = $route.current.params.name;
```

Or you can use $routeParams https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: Ok, and what I need to enter inside the HTML ?

Comment: So, you are trying to access the 'appPath' when making a post request, correct? In that case, get the path using the $route and pass it in your API call. Is that what u looking for??

Comment: how I can do it using the $route?

Comment: Here is the small snippet for reference., you can use $route either in controller or service. 
`app.controller(‘controller’, ['$route',  function ($route) {
    var currentMethod = $route.current.params.name;

   }]);`

Comment: I hope you are using routes to navigate to different views if so you can use this approach. If you are not using routes then u need to get the "currentpage" manually and pass it in your API call.

Comment: No sir, I am not using routes. How can I make this manually ?

Comment: "ngInit", may solve your problem but not the best solution. You can call ng-init from your template to get the 'currentPage' value in your controller. 
`<ul class="pager" ng-show="currentPage==login" ng-init="someFuntion(currentPage)">` and access the currentPage value., worth giving it a try. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit